# Воскрешение сына Наинской вдовы. Почему Наинской с прописной буквы?

Tags: орфография, морфемика

Из вики:
Воскрешение сына Наинской вдовы[en] (фр. la résurrection du fils de la veuve de Naïm; англ. Resurrection of the son of the widow of Nain) — библейский эпизод, евангельская история воскрешения в городе Наине[en][1] умершего юноши, «единственного сына у матери, а она была вдова» (Лук. 7:11—18); сюжет художественных произведений:

«Воскрешение сына Наинской вдовы» — гравюра Джованни Фоло (1764—1836).
«Воскрешение сына Наинской вдовы» — икона живописца Василия Шебуева (1777—1855) в Исаакиевском соборе.
«Воскрешение сына Наинской вдовы» — картина Луи-Жюля Этекса (1810—1889)
«Воскрешение сына Наинской вдовы» (1855) — картина Александра Бейдемана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Наинская вдова** — это известное лицо из евангельской истории, и это сочетание здесь употребляется  **в качестве имени собственного**, так как настоящее ее имя неизвестно или не называется.